# How to parse JSON File to Object

Tags: java, json

I have below item, how to parse the nested object into java variable. I am using JSON document but not sure how to parse the sub object. Please see the JSON item and java code

JSON:

```
{
        "_id" : "328",
        "website" : "www.abc.com",
        "addresses" : [
                {
                        "addressType" : "PRIMARY",               
                        "address" : "102 Yonge Street",
                        "city" : "Toronto",
                        "postalCode" : "M2N 6T6",
                        "state" : {
                                "code" : "ON",
                                "name" : "Ontario",
                                "countryCode" : "CA"
                        },
                        "country" : "Canada"
                },
                {
                        "addressType" : "SECONDARY",
                        "address" : "180 Yonge Street",
                        "city" : "Toronto",
                        "postalCode" : "L6P 6T7",
                        "state" : {
                                "code" : "ON",
                                "name" : "Ontario",
                                "countryCode" : "CA"
                        },
                        "country" : "Canada"
                }
        ],
        "phoneNumber" : "123456"
}
```

Java Code:

```
DynamicMappingFile objDynoMapping = new DynamicMappingFile();
    ConfigReader objConfigReader = new ConfigReader();

    public String strSQL(String strFullDocument)
    {

        String sqlInsertStatement = "";
        System.out.println("Value of strFullDocument is " + strFullDocument);
        String lstrInsertColumnStatement ="";
        String charAfterColumnStatement = ")";
        String lstrInsertValuesStatement ="values (";
        String lstrColumnValues = "";
        String lstrBSONDocValue = "";
        String lstrColumnName;
        int columnIndex = 0;
        int documentLength = BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).size();
        final BufferedReader br;
        String lstrMySQLColumneName="";
        String MySQLColumnNames = "";
        String lstrMongoandMySQLDBFields="";
        int lstrBSONDoubleValue = 0;


        try {
              br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./Configuration/MongoMySQLMapping.csv"));

             lstrInsertColumnStatement = lstrInsertColumnStatement.concat("Insert into " + objConfigReader.mySQLTable + " (");
             System.out.println("Value of Insert statement is : " + lstrInsertColumnStatement);
                while(br.ready()){
                     lstrMongoandMySQLDBFields = br.readLine(); //Skip the header line
                     System.out.println(lstrMongoandMySQLDBFields);
                     objDynoMapping.add(objDynoMapping.new MapFields(lstrMongoandMySQLDBFields));
                }
        }
        catch(Exception errBuff) {
            System.out.println(errBuff.toString());
        }

        System.out.println("Length of Document is " + documentLength);

        lstrColumnName = BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).keySet().toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");

        System.out.println("value of lstrcolumnname");

        Set<String> setKeys = BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).keySet();


        Iterator<String> itr = setKeys.iterator();

        System.out.println("Value of keys");
        while(itr.hasNext())

       {


            System.out.println("Inside while");
        String keys = (String) itr.next();

    lstrMySQLColumneName = objDynoMapping.lsMapFields.get(keys).keySet().toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    System.out.println("lstrMySQLColumneName" + lstrMySQLColumneName);

        if(BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).get(keys).isObjectId())
        {

            System.out.println("Inside object id");
            lstrBSONDocValue = (String)BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).get(keys).asObjectId().getValue().toString();

            System.out.println("lstrBSONDocValue is" + lstrBSONDocValue);

          }

     else if(BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).get(keys).isString())
     {
    //   details[i] = BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).get(keys).asString().getValue();
         System.out.println("Inside else of string");
         lstrBSONDocValue = (String)BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).get(keys).asString().getValue();

     System.out.println("Value is " + lstrColumnValues);

    //   System.out.println("Value of details is " + details[i]);


     }

     else if(BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).get(keys).isInt32())
     {
    //   details[i] = BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).get(keys).asString().getValue();

         System.out.println("Inside int value");

         lstrBSONDocValue = String.valueOf(BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).get(keys).asInt32().getValue());



          System.out.println("Value is " + lstrBSONDoubleValue);


    //   System.out.println("Value of details is " + details[i]);


     }




        if(columnIndex!=documentLength-1)
        {
            System.out.println("insode column index");

            MySQLColumnNames = MySQLColumnNames.concat(lstrMySQLColumneName + ",");

            if(BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).get(keys).isObjectId())
            {
                System.out.println("Before is " + lstrColumnValues);
                lstrColumnValues = lstrColumnValues.concat("\"" + lstrBSONDocValue + "\",");
                System.out.println("After is " + lstrColumnValues);

            }

            if(BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).get(keys).isString())
            {
                System.out.println("Before is " + lstrColumnValues);
                lstrColumnValues = lstrColumnValues.concat("\"" + lstrBSONDocValue + "\",");
                System.out.println("After is " + lstrColumnValues);

            }

            if(BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).get(keys).isInt32())
            {
                System.out.println("Before is " + lstrColumnValues);
                lstrColumnValues = lstrColumnValues.concat(String.valueOf(lstrBSONDocValue) + ",");
                System.out.println("After is " + lstrColumnValues);

            }


        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Insode else column");
            MySQLColumnNames = MySQLColumnNames.concat(lstrMySQLColumneName);

            if(BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).get(keys).isObjectId())
            {
                System.out.println("Before is " + lstrColumnValues);
                lstrColumnValues = lstrColumnValues.concat("\"" + lstrBSONDocValue + "\",");
                System.out.println("After is " + lstrColumnValues);

            }

            if(BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).get(keys).isString())
            {
                System.out.println("Before is " + lstrColumnValues);
                lstrColumnValues = lstrColumnValues.concat("\"" + lstrBSONDocValue + "\"");
                System.out.println("After is " + lstrColumnValues);

            }

            if(BsonDocument.parse(strFullDocument).get(keys).isInt32())
            {
                System.out.println("Before is " + lstrColumnValues);
                lstrColumnValues = lstrColumnValues.concat(String.valueOf(lstrBSONDocValue));
                System.out.println("After is " + lstrColumnValues);

            }


      //    
       //   System.out.println("lstrColumnValues 1 is " + lstrColumnValues);


        }

        columnIndex++;

    }    
       sqlInsertStatement =  sqlInsertStatement.concat(lstrInsertColumnStatement + MySQLColumnNames + charAfterColumnStatement + lstrInsertValuesStatement + lstrColumnValues + ")");

        System.out.println("Final Value of Insert is " + sqlInsertStatement);




        return sqlInsertStatement;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain little more about what is your requirement, Are you trying to convert your mongo query to a Java  code?

Comment: Really unclear what you are asking, but I presume you actually have "exported JSON" in the `MongoMySQLMapping.csv` and you are trying to "parse JSON" and then insert it elsewhere? Kind of looks like you copied some existing code for working with a CSV format, but this is not CSV. If you have control over the MongoDB datasource then you might be able to export as CSV instead. But otherwise this is about "parsing JSON" and nothing to do with MongoDB